# Can I share my Wifi connection on my iPad?

Tags: iphone, ipad, network, wifi

I'll be going away in a couple of days, and I believe that where I am going, the WiFi is restricted to one device being connected at once. However, I would like to have internet access on both my iPhone and iPad Mini. Is there any way I can connect to the internet through my iPad Mini or vice verse, without a jailbreak?

Comment: Internet Sharing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iOS devices can not relay WiFi signals to other devices (at least not without a jailbreak). To share a single WiFi login with several devices you need to set up a WiFi repeater. Airport Express is one device which can do that, [D-Link 505](http://www.dlink.com/us/en/home-solutions/connect/portable-routers/dir-505-shareport-mobile-companion) is another one which I have successfully used for this purpose.

Comment: That is a shame. Just out of interest, would it be possible with jailbreak?

Comment: @Patrix, D-Link is a great device (for about $50), I do not know it, will it work with 110-200 Volts (60-50Hz)?  and could you explain how would you use jailbreak for Internet sharing? I might get one.

Comment: I don't jailbreak my devices so I can't comment on that in detail.

Comment: After jailbreaking my iPod Touch 4G and searching all morning, I can conclude that you can only create a WiFi hotspot from a cellular network and not from the iPod's WiFi connection. What's more, a jailbreak is only useful if your carrier does not *support* tethering, otherwise you can just create a Personal Hotspot! I hope somebody will find this information useful in the future.

Comment: @patrix Thank you for suggesting those devices, and for the answer itself. I will look into purchasing one of them for future trips, but unfortunately it is now to soon to get one. Although I might still be able to take an old EeePC that I have and run Connectify on it... We'll see. The chances are the the WiFi there wont even be good enough to share though :/

Comment: As long as the EeePC can pick up the signal you should be fine because the PC will run as a repeater and provide its own signal in your room.

Answer (score 2):

Just had the same issue in my hotel in the Dominican Republic, where I enjoy a great snow-free christmas. The hotel locks the DCHP to the MAC address of the first device that connects, thereby limiting usage to one device per paying customer--they think.

Just note the MAC address belonging to the wi-fi adapter of your first device and then you can soft-set that for each of your other MacBooks, Windows laptops or what have you. In OS X you can use…

```
sudo ifconfig en1 ether <your first device's MAC address>
```

…and then you are good to go. Turn wi-fi off on your first device. It's not perfect, but at least you do not have to pay multiple fees.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just one question, what do you mean by "hour Macbook" and "hour first device"?

Answer (score 1):

Not in any reasonable manner. Instead, use a portable WISP router.  This creates your own local WiFi network yet uses the hotel connection as the WAN.  Some are no bigger than your finger if you're concerned about size of this additional hardware component.

Answer (score 0):

Use iPad mini as a personal hotspot.

From Apple
**[Where supported](http://manuals.info.apple.com/en_US/ipad_user_guide.pdf)**, iPad mini can share its high-speed data connection as a personal hotspot.

You can connect up to five devices — such as a MacBook Air, an iPod touch, or another iPad — over Wi‑Fi, Bluetooth, or USB.

> Share an Internet connection: Go to Settings > General > Cellular and
>   tap Set Up Personal Hotspot —if it appears—to set up the service with
>   your carrier. After you turn on Personal Hotspot, other devices can
>   connect in the following ways: • W-Fi: On the device, choose your iPad
>   from the list of available Wi-Fi networks.

As @Patrix pointed out, it all depends where your "source" wifi comes from.

There is always a BUT :)

But, since you think you can get only one WiFi connection in the place you are going, try [Boingo](http://wifi.boingo.com/?lang=en), to see if they have something there.

In my case, when the hotels are trying to rip me off (like $20 per day for internet use), I use my unlocked phone, go to local store and buy a SIM with Internet for cheep.

Comment: I can't see an option to set it up as a personal hotspot in my settings though. I'm connected to unrestricted home wifi at the minute.

Comment: AFAIK Personal Hotspot only works with 3G/4G connection on the outbound, not as a WiFi relay.

Comment: This answer is really not that good to me then, because I'll only have a WiFi connection. Although @Buscar can you elaborate on the alternative. I don't quite understand.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail how Internet Connection sharing can be set up under iOS?

Comment: Since you have only a wifi version, than that would not work for you.  Personal Hotspot works only if iPad is connected to the Internet over the cellular data network.

Comment: +1 because your answer is informative but yes, I do have the WiFi only version so it isn't really the solution. Isn't there any app to do this? Just out of interest, if I jailbroke my iPod Touch would I be able to set that up as a WiFi hotspot?

Comment: :) thanks, I should have had it clarified with you before giving my answer. Also please explain how can a wifi be restricted to one per user only, unless it is paid type and you want to save on cost.

Comment: @Buscar웃 It's ok. And yes, I'm going abroad. The hotel offers WiFi access but only one device can be logged at once (you have to enter a code) and the price is crazy.

Comment: Ha, regarding your latest edit - if you had said 20 euros you'd have been spot on. Thanks for the tip, might have to see what I can find when I get there, although if memory serves me I'm not sure I'll be that successful in Lanzarote

Comment: Welcome neighbor :) I would lend you my wifi but we are not so close (I am in Benalmadena).

Answer (score 0):

Most hotel/resort captive portals require you to pay for each device that is connected to the WiFi, if you want access to the outside world.  It is more than likely possible that you could pay twice, (Onnce for your iPad, once for your iPhone) and get the same results..

Spoofing the MAC address on one of your iOS devices is non-trivial and would require jailbreaking.  Also, to have two devices with the name MAC on the same network at the same time will cause problems.  Simultaneous use is out of the question - in fact you will need to turn one device off in order to use the second device for any period of time.

Also..  will you have a cellular data connection?  Can the iPhone continue to use this data connection, while you iPad uses the WiFi?

I know that none of the above actually provides you with the answer you were looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your input, it doesn't really matter to me that you haven't provided me with the answer I am looking for now. I know for a fact that I can pay for more than one device, but having been before - I know that there prices are just too high to be doing that. Similarly, my iPhone will most likely receive a phone signal there but I don't know if it will be strong enough to be able to surf the internet, and I don't want to become a victim of mobile data prices abroad either.

Answer (score 0):

You could buy a Dlink 506l device -   It will do this.  $44 from Amazon.   You can also use it as a travel router or to stream/share files from a USB drive.

It does a lot for $44.   But needs a firmware upgrade (easy) to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Sharing internet connection from one iPhone to another works well if one of the iPhone has a valid Data Simcard with internet and personal hotspot is turn on. 
Once you have done that turn on the wi-fi on the other iPhone that has no internet and let it search search...once detected connect it, that's it. It works well for me and my friends.